# closure onload keydown all at once

Tags: javascript, jquery

Well, the code below works perfectly, 
but I have tried to use it with closures 
(an advanced and interesting feature of js)
but without success.
I would like some suggestions of how to make this work with closures
(and avoiding memory leaks, something I have read about closures). 
And if possible, I would like this code to work only after the whole page (and
images are loaded). 
This is not something I need to get done, but some
improvement (and kind of a challenge). A good way to learn, I guess. Here
is the code. 
You can use any beautiful image as 01.jpg and 02.jpg (beautiful
landscapes maybe). Any help is appreciated. (by the way, spacer.gif is
a 1x1 pixel transparent image).

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">

<html>

<head>
<title>Wow</title>

<script src="jquery-1.12.3.min.js"></script>

<style type="text/css">
    body{ margin-top: 0 !important; 
          margin-bottom: 0 !important; 
          text-align: center; background-color:#FFFFFF; }

    .imgsea { display: block; width: 965px; height: 1885px; alt=""; }
    .imginv { display: block; width: 965px; height: 8px; alt=""; }
    .imghnt { display: block; width: 965px; height: 40px; alt=""; }

</style>
</head>


<body>
<img src="spacer.gif" class="imghnt"> 

<img src="01.jpg" class="imgsea"> 
<img src="spacer.gif" class="imginv"> 
<img src="02.jpg" class="imgsea"> 
<img src="spacer.gif" class="imghnt">

</body>

<script>

    var posiciones = [0, 636, 1270, 1903, 2536, 3180];
    var elementos = 6;
    var indis = 0;
    var mosca = 0;

    $("html, body").keydown(function(e){
        if (indis < 0) { indis = 0; }
        if (indis > elementos-1) { indis = elementos-1; }
        var code = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);
        if (code == 34) {
            //alert("page down pressed");
            e.stopImmediatePropagation();
            mosca = posiciones[++indis]; 
            $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: mosca }, 600); 
            return false;
        } 
        if (code == 33) {
            //alert("page up pressed");
            e.stopImmediatePropagation();
            mosca = posiciones[--indis]; 
            $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: mosca }, 600); 
            return false;
        }

    });

</script>

</html>
```

Comment: You can wrap up that whole thing in a anonymous function and call itself to clear up the namespace.

Comment: Or in the keydown callback, except return the function to be used.

Comment: $(window).bind("load", function() {
/* all the code in the script, previously described */
});

It seems to work, but does it solve it all? Is it so simple?

Comment: Yep! Memory leaks occur when you capture values in the closure that you don't want. Like if you've got a big object that will be null soon in the parent scope of the closure and that closure stores the object... That object won't get cleaned up! But remember: premature optimization is the root of all evil. Happy programming!